# Array inputs saves on all positions

Tags: java, arrays, position

I'm have a code were I'm trying to save an input in an array, but when i do it saves on all the positions. 
If my user inputs are Klas, Philip and Comp i get an output as:

Klas Philip from Comp with number 100 added

Klas Philip from Comp with number 101 added

Klas Philip from Comp with number 102 added

Klas Philip from Comp with number 103 added

But i do want the first user input to be saved as Klas Philip from Comp with number 100 added and the second input to  be saved on number 101 and so on. 
But now the first input Klas Philip from Comp saves on all numbers

Here's the code

```
    Class1[] all = new Class1[120];
    int quantity = 0;

        System.out.println("text: ");
        String x = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("text2:  ");
        String y = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("text 3: ");
        String z = keyboard.nextLine();

        Class1 p = new Class1(x, y, z);
        all[quantity++] = p;

        for (int i = 100; i < all.length; i++)
             System.out.println(p.getFirstName()+(" ")+p.getSurname()+" from " +p.getTeamName()+" with number " +(x) +" added");

        if (quantity == all.length){
            Class1[] temp = new Class1[all.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
                temp[i] = all[i];
            all = temp;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it very difficult to figure out what you want to achieve. Can you edit the question to make it more legible? You hardcode the length of the Class1 array to be 120, which is why you get the repeated print-outs.

Change

```
for (int i = 100; i < all.length; i++)
     System.out.println(p.getFirstName()+(" ")+p.getSurname()+" 
     from " +p.getTeamName()+" with number " +(x) +" added");
```

to

```
for (int i = 100; i < all.length; i++)
     System.out.println(p.getFirstName()+(" ")+p.getSurname()+" 
     from " +p.getTeamName()+" with number " +(i) +" added");
```

**to get the output you describe, i.e.:**

1. Klas Philip from Comp with number 100 added
2. Klas Philip from Comp with number 101 added

**Unless you mean that you want**

1. Klas Philip from Comp with number 100 added
2. Tom Baker from Gallifrey with number 101 added

In which case I would store every user input in an array or a List first, and then loop through it to print it out. E.g.:

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  List<Class1> all = new ArrayList<Class1>();
  int quantity = 0;
  while(quantity <2) // whatever the max number of entries should be
  {

        System.out.println("text: ");
        String x = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("text2:  ");
        String y = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("text 3: ");
        String z = keyboard.nextLine();

        Class1 p = new Class1(x, y, z);
        all.add(p);
        quantity++;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
             System.out.println(all.get(i).getFirstName()+(" ")+
             all.get(i).getSurname()+" from " +all.get(i).getTeamName()+" with number 
             " +(i) +" added");
```

Console output:

```
text: 
Jan
text2:  
Klaas
text 3: 
Huntelaar
text: 
Tom
text2:  
Baker
text 3: 
Gallifrey
Jan Klaas from Huntelaar with number 0 added
Tom Baker from Gallifrey with number 1 added
```